# Can I open visual basic .vbp files using gambas?

Tags: programming

I had installed gambas 2.21 but i cannot open .vbp files format. Why?
If it can, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

According to some documentation I have found on google:
http://www.arabteam2000-forum.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=51517

You should be able to import a VB project using Gambas "New Project" wizard.

Comment: it different from gambas that I using.. When I open New Project it only have graphical application.gtk+ application, qt application,command-line apllication,and cgi application

Answer (score 1):

You can use mono develop to rum MS VB apps.

http://www.mono-project.com/VisualBasic.NET_support